# Rally : document.referrer is not returning complete URL

Tags: rally

We have created a custom App using Rally SDK. We are providing link to this app in a custom field in USER story. Once we click on this link, it gets redirected to the App. Within this app, we want know from which User story it has redirected from.
For the same purpose we are making use of document.referrer. However, it only returns 'https://rally1.rallydev.com' and not the complete URL.

Based on our research, we come to know that meta tag for refferer with appropriate value has to be mentioned in the web page to get the complete URL. Which we think is not mentioned in this case.

Please correct if our understanding is wrong.
It will be very helpful if you could suggest any alternatives to achieve this.

Comment: What you are referring to, is the [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) response header. (Not sure though if that can be set via a meta tag as well.)

Comment: You might also be able to just add a query string parameter onto the end of the url with your custom info in it so you know where it came from...